Is death immoral according to emotivism?
Emotivism (A.J. Ayer) is the meta-ethical theory that our ethical statements can be analytically reduced to emotional reactions (boo, hurrah).
Death is an action which more often than not produces negative emotional reactions within those who are forced to witness it.
Is death therefore morally weighted, and is it immoral?

The abrahimic faiths propose immortality. Life after death if you are moral, or purgatory if you are not. Not any of these faith say your soul is not eternal. What's deyermined as immoral is a question of what you do whilst your in this world and not after.

Murder or suicide are actions, death itself is not. It is a natural event and, as such, is not subject to morality, amoral. That moral judgments can be reduced to emotional reactions and attitudes does not mean that every emotional reaction produces a moral judgment. Wild flowers are not morally good despite producing positive emotions, nor are floods and hurricanes morally bad despite producing negative ones. Not even all emotional reactions to actions are morally relevant, we also make aesthetic, pragmatic, etc., judgments. "He is a good thief" is not about moral approval.

@Conifold How would you define an action? Surely one would define it broadly, materialistically as something  resulting from biological processes within the human body, causing a change of physical state?

One can define action broadly, of course, but they would then have to distinguish morally relevant ones anyway. Even under physicalism, such actions would have to causally pass through higher brain functions at a minimum, see SEP, What is an Action?

You ask:

Is death immoral according to emotivism?

It's context dependent. Morality and immorality are classically related to guiding action and making sense of the world. First, recognize death is not an action (SEP); rather, it is a state of affairs. So, non-cognitive emotivism might say "Boo, death!", but as a meta-ethical principle it is more interested in interpreting action through that emotional lens. Thus, it is more interested in stating "Boo, killing babies!", "Boo, killing yourself!", "Boo, crushing puppies with cars!" (as per an individual's emotional constitution). Note, each essentially founds the basis for entailing proscriptions on infanticide, suicide, and canicide(?). From the SEP:

There is an important difference between activity and passivity: the fire is active with respect to the log when it burns it (and the log passive with respect to the fire). Within activity, there is also an important difference between the acts of certain organisms and the activities of non-living things like fire: when ants build a nest, or a cat stalks a bird, they act in a sense in which the fire does not. Finally, there is a long-standing tradition in philosophy going back at least as far as Plato and Aristotle that recognizes an important distinction between the acts that (non-human) animals in general are capable of, and the special sorts of actions that human beings do intentionally, such as going to the store, making phone calls, protesting an injustice, or knitting a sweater.

Therefore, a non-cognitive emotivist takes the view that while death is generally bad (there are cases where it is good, like "Yay, Hitler's dead!"), extended logical arguments are essentially psychological rationalizations that serve to efface one's emotional state. And that sort of argumentation is generally directed at the ethics of actions (since rationalizations are often justifications of decisions). So death is as the individual perceives it emotionally, and depends therefore on context of the particular boo or yay attached to that context.

Death is not immoral under any definition of morality. God's actions would be subject to moral questionability if he did not advocate immortality, which God does. Life and the judgement of god is if you contravene the morality of God. God is just as tempted as you to indulge in sin. It's the self control of God or anybody else that has self control is able to judge those that donot share their self control. Objectively or subjectively.if there's a difference?
